# create instance of model on AJAX call success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have a User model:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        handle: '',
        email: '',
        uuid: '',
        userpic: '',
        tokenlogin: ''
    }
});
```

I also have a collection called UserSignIn, although I'm not sure why:

```
var UserSignIn = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: UserModel });
```

And inside of my  SignInView view, I have the following function...

```
signIn: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.collection.fetch({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/app/api/User.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $.param({
            req: "REQUSERSIGNIN",
            platform: "WEB",
            useremail: $('#userSignIn #userEmail').val(),
            userpass: $('#userSignIn #userPassword').val()
        }),
        success: function(data) {

            // In here, I'd like to create an
            // instance of the model which I'd
            // like to pass around my app.

            var user = new UserModel({
                handle: data.HANDLE,
                email: data.EMAIL,
                uuid: data.UUIDUSER,
                userpic: data.USERPIC,
                tokenlogin: data.TOKENLOGIN
            });
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, all I am trying to do is create an instance of a User on success of the BackBone.fetch() function.

I'd like to understand how to then pass around this new "user" UserModel() instance around my app. When I try to `console.log(user)` I get a "ReferenceError: user is not defined" when clearly I just created it in the success callback of the fetch function.

Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to insert it into your collection if you wanna follow the right way in backbone.
I think that you can do this:

into your initialize in the view insert this:

```
initialize: function(){
   //..... your code in initialize
   this.userModel = null;
   this.collection = new UserCollection();
},


signIn: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var here = this;
    this.collection.fetch({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/app/api/User.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: $.param({
            req: "REQUSERSIGNIN",
            platform: "WEB",
            useremail: $('#userSignIn #userEmail').val(),
            userpass: $('#userSignIn #userPassword').val()
        }),
        success: function(data) {
             var user = {handle: data.HANDLE,email: data.EMAIL,uuid: data.UUIDUSER,userpic: data.USERPIC,tokenlogin: data.TOKENLOGIN};
            here.userModel = new UserModel(user);
            here.collection.addUser(here.userModel);
        }
    });
}
```

You UserCollection must be something like this:

```
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel,
    initialize:function(){
        console.log('Initialized User collection');
    },
        addUser: function(users, options) {
            return this.add(users, options);
        }
});
```

To console each element of your collection you can try this (if you run this code inside your success function use `here` instead of `this`):

```
this.collection.each(function(user, index) {
    console.log(user);
    //if you want to set a value of your model:
    user.set('email', 'yournewemail@email.it');
    //if you want to get some value
    user.get('email');                          
});
```

Comment: How do I then get access the new user in the userModel? For example, how would I console.log to see the collection's contents?

Comment: edit my answer with an each to console log all your models inside the collection @iggy2012

Comment: These aren't available globally? How would I pass the user data around to different parts of my app?

Comment: yes is available into your app with this.collection... collection is a sort of container of your models @iggy2012

Comment: I see. So am I correct in assuming that you never ever interact with models, always with collections? For this particular app, all I am doing is signing in a user and then getting that single user's data to pass around the app.

Comment: I have added some functionality inside the each, well, you can interact with the model but you have to pass from the collection, if you don't want to use the collection you can access directly to the model but you can store only one model. I have seen that you have already a collection and I ave follow this way @iggy2012

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37611/discussion-between-iggy2012-and-alessandro-minoccheri)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `user` is scoped only to within the `success` function of your SignInView view, so you can't `console.log(user)` which is looking for a `user` variable from  the global scope. You could put `console.log(user)` right after creating the user within the `success` function to see that it is created, since this would find the local variable `user`.

To access it from the app, you could also declare `var user;` outside the fetch function and then simply set it within the `fetch` function.